# How to create an instance of an object in SwiftUI without duplication?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This is the next part of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859985/how-to-create-object-instance-for-detail-view-in-swiftui) question.

I've got the follow code.

The initial view of the app:

```swift
struct InitialView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Group { 
            PresentationButton(destination: ObjectsListView()) {
                Text("Show ListView")
            }
            PresentationButton(destination: AnotherObjectsListView()) {
                Text("Show AnotherListView")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The list view of the objects:

```swift
struct ObjectsListView : View {

    @Environment(\.myObjectsStore.objects) var myObjectsStores: Places

    var body: some View {
        Group {    
            Section {
                ForEach(myObjectsStore.objects) { object in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ObjectDetailView(object: object)) {
                        ObjectCell(object: object)
                    }
                }
            }
            Section {
                // this little boi
                PresentationButton(destination: ObjectDetailView(objectToEdit: MyObject(store: myObjectsStore))) {
                    Text("Add New Object")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The detail view:

```swift
struct ObjectsDetailView : View {

    @Binding var myObject: MyObject    

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(myObject.title)")
    }
}
```

So the problem is quite complex.

1. The `ObjectsListView` creates instance of the `MyObject(store: myObjectsStore)` on itself initialization while computing `body`.
2. The `MyObject` object is setting its `store` property on itself initialization, since it should know is it belongs to `myObjectsStore` or to `anotherMyObjectsStore`.
3. The `myObjectsStore` are @BindableObjects since their changes are managing by SwiftUI itself.

So this behavior ends up that I've unexpected `MyObject()` initializations since the Views are computing itself. Like:

- First `MyObject` creates on the `ObjectsListView` initialization.
- Second `MyObject` creates on its `PresentationButton` pressing (the expected one).
- Third (any sometimes comes even fourth) `MyObject` creates on dismissing `ObjectsDetailView`.

So I can't figure what pattern should I use this case to create only one object?

The only thing that I'd come to is to make the follow code:

```swift
struct ObjectsListView : View {

    @Environment(\.myObjectsStore.objects) var myObjectsStores: Places

    @State var buttonPressed = false

    var body: some View {
        Group {    
            if buttonPressed {
                ObjectDetailView(objectToEdit: MyObject(store: myObjectsStore))
            } else {

                Section {
                    ForEach(myObjectsStore.objects) { object in
                        NavigationLink(destination: ObjectDetailView(object: object)) {
                            ObjectCell(object: object)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Section {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.buttonPressed.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Add New Object")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which simply redraw `ObjectsListView` to detail view conditionally. But it's completely out of iOS guidelines. So how to create the **Only One** object for another view in SwiftUI?

**UPD:**
Here's the [project](https://github.com/yaroslavyaroslav/SwiftUITestBug) that represents the bug with Object duplication.
I'm still have no idea why the objects are duplicating in this case. But at least I know the reason yet. And the reason is this line:

`@Environment(\.myObjectsStore.objects) var myObjectsStores: Places`

I've tried to share my model with this wrapper to make it available in every single view (including Modal one) without passing them as an arg to the new view initializer, which are unavailable by the other ways, like `@EnvironmentObject` wrapper. And for some reason `@Environment(\.keyPath)` wrapper makes duplications.

So I'd simply replace all variables from `Environment(\.)` to `ObjectBinding` and now everything works well.

Comment: I just tested this out with dummy objects, and I saw one initialization, and it was when the view's body was calculated. I did not see another initialization when the `PresentationButton` was tapped or when the view was dismissed. Are you sure the object is initialized multiple times? How do you know (print statement in object's `init`?)? Are the extra objects duplicates of the one you want to create or are they different?

Comment: @RPatel99 Thanks to you I've found the solution. Thank you for your support! I'd update the question with the example project in which first commit are represents the duplication bug, and second shows fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to this.

[Here's](https://github.com/yaroslavyaroslav/SwiftUITestBug) the project repo that represents the bug with Object duplication and the version that fix this. I'm still have no idea how objects have been duplicate in that case. But I figured out why. It happens because this line:

`@Environment(\.myObjectsStore.objects) var myObjectsStores: MyObjectsStore`

I've used `@Environment(\.key)` to connect my model to each view in the navigation stack including `Modal` one, which are unavailable by the other ways provided in SwiftUI, e.g.: `@State`, `@ObjectBinding`, `@EnvironmentObject`. And for some reason `@Environment(\.key)` wrapper produce these duplications.

So I'd simply replace all variables from `@Environment(\.)` to `@ObjectBinding` and now almost everything works well.

**Note:** The code is in the rep is still creates one additional object by each workflow walkthrough. So it creates two objects totally instead of one. This behavior could be fixed by way provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56563652/7136628).